# how retrive data from sql databse and that data should be shown in jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hi guys please help me I doing a expense sheet project in that project I have already done most of the coding n database connection is also working.
my pblm is when ill click SAVE button the data goes into database but it is not shown in the jtable pls let me know if hav any solution..

thanks

Comment: What did you try? Show us your relevant code. We cannot guess your code and your faults...

Comment: You'll have to pass in a new model with the updated data to the JTable. That's my best guess without seeing ANY EXAMPLE OR ANY CODE OR ANY EXPLANATION.

Comment: You don't necessarily _have_ to retrieve the data again from the database, if you are getting input from the gui. You can just add a row to the table model.

Comment: You should search for a tutorial and then work with it. If you have any concrete issue please come back and the community will try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean to get a resultset and display it in a JTable, then you will have to use ResultSetMetaData in order to get the metadata like column names and row and column count to make a table model.

Check you this [link](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to retrieve the table names and actual data from table. and then save this in separate variables. The class `JTable` is used to draw a table.

In Vector `tblData` there could be values like : `{"Name1", "22", "Male"}`

while in `tblHeads` it may contain values like : `{"Name", "Age", "Gender"}`

```
JTable joriginaldata_Table = new JTable(tblData, tblHeads);
```

where `tblData` is a vector containing actual data that will be contained in a table, while `tblHeads` is a vector containing table heads.

Answer (score 0):

> *"..my pblm is when ill click SAVE button the data goes into database but it is not shown in the jtable.."*

If you are using a `TableModel` you can just get the text from the fields of the gui and add the data to the table. No need to update the table from the database.

```
String[] cols = {"column1", "column2", "column3"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(cols, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);

....

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    // example
    String someString1 = someTextField1.getText();
    String someString2 = someTextField1.getText();
    String someString3 = someTextField1.getText();

    // database input here

    Object[] row = {someString1, someString1, someString3};

    model.addRow(row);
}
```